# can't find ganglia.conf after configure conmand

Tags: ganglia

I want to use ganglia to watch over my hbase group, but after I ran this conmand:

`"./configure --with-gmetad --enable-gexec --with-libconfuse=/usr/local/confuse --with-libexpat=/usr/local/expat --prefix=/usr/local/ganglia --sysconfdir=/etc/ganglia"`

also followed by `"make"` and `"make install"`, I can't find ganglia.conf anywhere on the computer, not in /etc,not in usr/local/etc ,where can I find it? Didn't I put it in etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try /etc/httpd/conf.d/ganglia.conf

Answer (score 0):

Usually, installation of ganglia does not generate conf files.

After installation you need to execute below command to generate gmond.conf file:

```
gmond -t | tee /etc/ganglia/gmond.conf
```

Note: gmond.conf is the configuration file for gmond daemon of ganglia.

Similarly gmetad.conf can be found in the extracted dir of tar ball. For example, here,

`ganglia-3.6.0/gmetad/gmetad.conf`

I am using ganglia for server monitoring and I have never heard of any file named as ganglia.conf

Hope this answers what you asked.